# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: on getEmbeddedPicture at MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, mediametadataretriever

I want to get cover image from mp3 file, but `OutOfMemoryError` occurs

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(filePath);
    byte[] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();//here OutOfMemory



 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 5021932 byte allocation with 997784 free bytes and 974KB until OOM
                                                                            at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:404)
```

Comment: How heavy is your file at `filePath`?

Comment: @azizbekian 14Mb

Comment: Try applying [`android:largeHeap="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap).